# How to save indexed arrays to a session with a for loop?

Tags: php

This is basic stuff but I seem to be way too beginner to make it work. Down here I would like to somehow get my 100 arrays into different sessions, but anything like that does not seem to work and I wonder why?

```
for($i=1; $i<=100; $i++) {
    $age = rand(1,100);
    $table[] = $age;
    $_SESSION[$i] = $table[];
    }
```

Later I need to be able to echo $age of all 100 sessions printed also using for loop. If I do like down there again it just says about undefined override and gives number of all 100 $i's.

```
for($i=1; $i<=100; $i++) {
    echo $_SESSION[$i];
    }
```

Comment: `$_SESSION[$i] = $age`?

Comment: Why don't you just add your complete array to a particular session key? `$_SESSION['ages'] = $table`

Answer (score 1):

```
for($i=1; $i<=100; $i++) {
    $age = rand(1,100);
    $ages[] = $age;
}

$_SESSION['ages'] = $ages;
```

In your other script

```
$ages = $_SESSION['ages'];
foreach($ages as $age) {
    echo $age;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
for($i=1; $i<=100; $i++) {
    $age = rand(1,100);
    $table[] = $_SESSION["ages"][$i] = $age;
}
```

Comment: This is still invalid PHP syntax. You may not set a numeric index to the `$_SESSION` superglobal

Answer (score 0):

You cannot work with `$_SESSION` as if it were a normal array, it isn't. You may not use numeric indexes when using `$_SESSION`. The below code is completely invalid and will cause notices and may potentially cause your `$_SESSION` to not be populated you expect

```
// bad code!

$_SESSION[1] = 'foo'; // error
$_SESSION[] = 'bar'; // error
for ($i = 1; $i <= 100; $i++) {
    $_SESSION[$i] = rand(1, 100); // error 100x
}
```

Like Bram Gerritsen suggest in his answer I would change the code to be something like:

```
for($i=1; $i<=100; $i++) {
    $age = rand(1,100);
    $ages[] = $age;
}

$_SESSION['ages'] = $ages;
```

---

Fore more information [check out this PHP bug report](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=42472).